# how to get the chart size (CustomLabels、Chart)

Tags: c#, charts

This is a chart picture, and Top of the chart are CustomLabels.

I want to know the "HeightA" and "HeightB" by pixel.

But i only can get the Chart size. Is there every possible to get those Height?

[image]

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Besides, there's no such thing as "C# charts". There are ASP.NET Charts, WPF Charts, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your edited.  At the beginning , i thought that can help the title more clearly. Sorry , I will remember that...

Comment: Yes, you can look into the ChartArea.Position and the InnerPlotPositions.